# Test a method with mockito, which uses some utility methods of some other class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a method which receive a message of from a queue and I need to write the unit test for this method with `Mockito`. The method uses a utility class `UtilClass`. I am confused about how to write the unit test for this method

```
public boolean findSomeRecord(Message<?> message){
    Details details = UtilClass.getHeaderValue(Constants.DETAILS, message, Details.class);

    Record record = recordService.findById(details.getDetailsId());

    if(record == null ){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what you wrote so far?

Comment: Can I mock the UtilClass in my unit test? @Jobin

Comment: without mocking that static call you can write the test..
you dont need to mock the util class, just mock `recordService.findById`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer: it *depends*.

I guess your first problem is that this **static** method call `UtilClass.getHeaderValue()` doesn't function correctly in your unit test?

You see, because if it would function ... what would you care about it? Meaning: you want to test that `findSomeRecord()` returns either true or false. So, in a **perfect** setup, you would only have two tests like:

```
assertThat(objectUnderTest.findSomeRecord(someRecordThatCanBeFound), is(true));
```

resp.

```
assertThat(objectUnderTest.findSomeRecord(someRecordThatCanNotBeFound), is(false));
```

But probably that **static** method doesn't work that way in your unit test setup. Then you have two choices:

1. You turn to PowerMock(ito); which allows you to **mock** static methods
2. You change your design; for example by **giving** up on the idea that this util method is a **static** method. Because when you are not calling a static method, you can (almost) always use **dependency injection** to give your production code a **mocked** object to to call its methods on.

Comment: Actually I cannot change the design of the production method which uses UtilClass's static method, nor I can use PowerMOck because I am restricted to use only Mockito

Comment: Then **nobody** can help you. Your requirements are then constraining you so much that no reasonable testing is possible.

Comment: Or to be precise: that depends if you can at least provide a **mocked** recordService object to your method. If calling getHeaderValue() does return something, then you are still good.

Comment: That makes sense.. Thank you

Comment: Actually your last comment quickly resolved the issue that I was facing